# Do small businesses that are on the Internet grow twice as fast?

Tags: internet, google, business

Google claims in their [Project Loon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Loon) [video](https://youtu.be/m96tYpEk1Ao) ([1:07](https://youtu.be/m96tYpEk1Ao?t=67)) that (transcription mine):

> And because small businesses that are on the internet grow twice as fast, everyone could create new opportunities for everyone.

Ironically, [searching Google itself](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=small%20business%20internet%20twice%20as%20fast&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=S4iYV9nWD4uDvATkrbOwAw#safe=off&q=small%20business%20on%20the%20internet%20grow%20twice%20as%20fast) does not turn up any useful evidence that this statement is true.

Is the claim by Google true?

Comment: This is relevant to all "fastest growing" claims: https://xkcd.com/1102/.

Comment: I think this needs better definition to answer.  Does 'on the internet' mean a primarily e-business company that makes it's profits using internet and electronics, or simply possessing a website count?  The latter seems hard to prove, since most companies generally create a website once the reach a certain rate of growth it may be hard to get a sufficient control of non-web companies that are seriously advertising to compare against.

Comment: On the xkcd theme, there clearly could be a [correlation-causality](https://xkcd.com/552/) issue here

Comment: "Twice as fast" as what?